# How can I access object from component in my constant?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, constants

I have a component that has several functions that subscribes to data returned from an observable in my service. This is working properly, but I would like to refactor my code so I can access that data in my constant and simply loop through the data in my view.

The problem I'm having is when I want to read a property on my object from my constant e.g. `value: this.price.market_price_usd,` I get a undefined error in my console. I've also tried to interpolate data by doing something like `value: '${this.price.market_price_usd}',`. This simply just returns a string. It appears the problem is that my constant is not aware of this data. How can I refactor my code so I can access this data in my constant and read it in my template? Below is the relevant code.

**Component**

```
constructor(private data: DataService) {
    this.loadstate = data.loadstate;
    this.subscription = data.nameChange.subscribe((value) => {
        this.loadstate = value;
    });
}

getPrice() {
    this.data.getData(this.API_Price)
    .subscribe( 
        price => this.price = price,
        error => this.errorMessage_price = <any>error);

}

getBlockSize() {
    this.data.getData(this.API_Block_Size)
    .subscribe(
        size => this.size = size.toFixed(2),
        error => this.errorMessage_size = <any>error);
}

getTransactions() {
    this.data.getData(this.API_Transactions)
    .subscribe(
        transactions => this.transactions = transactions.values.slice(-1)[0].y.toLocaleString(),
        error => this.errorMessage_transactions = <any>error);
}

getMempool() {
    this.data.getData(this.API_Mempool)
    .subscribe(
        mempool => this.mempool = Math.trunc(mempool.values[0].y).toLocaleString(),
        error => this.errorMessage_mempool = <any>error);
}
```

**Constant**

```
export const statsConstant = {
STATS: {
    ERROR: {
        message_1: 'There is a problem connecting to the API.',
        message_2: 'Please wait a moment and try again.'
    },
    ROW_1: [
    {
        title: 'Market Price USD',
        value: this.price.market_price_usd,
        error: 'errorMessage_price',
        errorMessage_1: 'There is a problem connecting to the API.',
        errorMessage_2: 'Please wait a moment and try again.',
        subtitle: 'Average USD market price across major bitcoin exchanges',
        symbol: 'USD'
    },
    {
        title: 'Average Block Size',
        value: this.size,
        error: 'errorMessage_size',
        errorMessage_1: 'There is a problem connecting to the API.',
        errorMessage_2: 'Please wait a moment and try again.',
        subtitle: 'The 24 hour average block size in MB.',
        symbol: 'Megabytes'
    }
    ],
    ROW_2: [
    {
        title: 'Transactions per Day',
        subtitle: 'The aggregate number of confirmed Bitcoin transactions in the past 24 hours.'
    },
    {
        title: 'Mempool Size',
        subtitle: 'The aggregate size of transactions waiting to be confirmed.'
    }
    ]
}
}
```

**Template**

```
 <div class="row">
    <div 
        class="col-sm-6 stats"
        *ngFor="let stat of stats.STATS.ROW_1">
        <div class="u-centerX">
            <h5>{{stat.title}}</h5>
        </div>
         <div class="u-centerX">
            <div 
                class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"
                *ngIf="stat.error === true">
                <p>{{stat.errorMessage_1}}.</p>
                <p>{{stat.errorMessage_2}}.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-centerX">
             <div 
                *ngIf="loadstate"
                class="loader">
            </div>
            <div
                *ngIf="price.market_price_usd"
                class="stats-data">
                <a href="https://blockchain.info/charts/market-price">
                    <h1>${{stat.value}}</h1>
                    <span>{{stat.symbol}}</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-centerX">
            <p>{{stat.subtitle}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What any of the `this.data.getData(...)` calls do?

Comment: Chances are when your template finished loading, the calls to get the data haven’t done yet

Comment: That calls a function on my service that returns data. I am then subscribing to that data so I can access it in my component.

Comment: @ChauTran That is incorrect because if I don't use a constant my data is loading correctly. I'm just refactoring so I can loop through it instead of doing it four separate times.

Comment: here’s why your refactoring doesnt work. You assign the value: this.price.... At the time you assign this value, this.price might have not gotten the value from the call yet. You said if you use the property directly, this.price gets updated after the call hence your template gets the value. It doesn’t work that way for a constant. However, you can construct an Interface and declare a property with that Interface to take in your data instead.

Comment: @ChauTran Okay, so how do I proceed? Construct an interface and then reference the interface in the constant?

Comment: I’d definitely show you when I get on a computer, given no one has answered. And yeah, construct an interface then declare `myData: Interface` then assign value to this myData

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a constant for dynamically changing data. A constant - as its name tells - is constant and can't receive value changes. But as you are requesting your values asynchronously, you have value changes for sure.

But the solution should be simple:

1. Don't declare `statsConstant` as `const` but as a property of your Components' class. Now values can be mutated when your async calls return.
2. Initialize the dynamic values (e.g. `stats.value`) with empty values. I would choose `null` here.
3. Overwrite the emtpy values with the actual values as soon as your async calls return with the data. After that your view should update automatically.

After that there should be no more need to additionally assign `this.price` and `this.size`.

You spoke about refactoring. My suggestion would be to move all that stats data structure and fetching it to an own service. Your component could then only use this single service API to get the whole stats data. Your service would be responsible for building it up. This would be cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I don't fully understand. How would I overwrite the value? I'm not sure I follow what you mean when you say move all of the stats data structure into it's own service. Currently, I already have a service that fetches this data.

Comment: Let&#39;s say you move your constant to a component&#39;s property named `stats`, you simply access the price value by `this.stats.STATS.ROW_1[0].value`. So within your Subscription callbacks you assign the price you get from your Backend to this property. Try this first, before you put everything into a new service like I said.